How to override/replace ForwardedHeaderTransformer?
I want to replace default ForwardedHeaderTransformer with mine to implement headers handling just for a predefined list of my trusted proxies by redefining its apply method. But cannot find how to do that. Could someone show me a complete example how to do that with spring boot 6+? Or maybe there's another way to implement it?
What I tried:
@Component
public class ConditionalForwardedHeaderTransformer extends ForwardedHeaderTransformer {
    @Override
    public ServerHttpRequest apply(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddress();
        return super.apply(request);
    }
}

Does not work
@Configuration
public class ConditionalForwardedHeaderTransformer extends ForwardedHeaderTransformer {
    @Override
    public ServerHttpRequest apply(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddress();
        return super.apply(request);
    }

    @Bean("forwardedHeaderTransformer")
    public ForwardedHeaderTransformer forwardedHeaderTransformer() {
        return new ConditionalForwardedHeaderTransformer();
    }
}

Does not work as well. I observe bean has been created but never called for any request.
I have server.forward-headers-strategy=framework set and it works fine. I also tried without setting this property but with no success.
Please help. Thank you!

@tekdungtralala Not yet. Probably should have asked on spring support groups and/or try newer version. Looks more like a bug

@tekdungtralala tbh it’s probably easier to trace/debug it with the current sources. Unfortunately had no time to check yet
